# Fluent Validation and Data Annotations - Problems with Required

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I have a prototype MVC 5 project.

In this project I have a model called Post:

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(PostValidator))]
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Title",ResourceType=typeof(PostResource))]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Content", ResourceType = typeof(PostResource))]
    public string Content { get; set; }
```

PostValidator:

```
public class PostValidator : AbstractValidator<Post>
{
    public PostValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(post => post.Title).NotNull();
        RuleFor(post => post.Content).NotNull();
    }
}
```

as it is, it ain't gonna work. Because I have FluentValidation Validator and I have the `[Required]` DataAnnotation in the model. So it throws an Exception.

```
Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: required
```

**SO HERE IS MY QUESTION AND PROBLEM:**

I want to make the Title and Content not null. Even if a DB manager goes there and puts a null value he can't. And that's achieved with the `[Required]` DataAnnotation making it `nullable=false`.

But if I can't use it with FluentValidation how can I solve this problem without haveing to carry migrations all around.

Comment: can you post your PostValidator?

Comment: updated with validator

Comment: I used FluentApi to add the nullable=false filed to the table. But I really don't think it's good code. To just add everytime. If there was any chance without having to write FluentAPI code for very single required field, I would love to see it